# How can I draw this in LaTeX?

Tags: tikz-pgf

[image]

How can I drew these boxes in LaTeX, especially how to put the arrows inside the box?

Comment: Welcome! Is this homework?

Comment: Welcome! The wisenheimer answer would be _"by using TikZ"_. What have you tried so far? Anything in particular you're struggling with?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it shows no research effort and clearly represents homework (a do-it-for-me post).

Comment: The arrows do look tricky for someone new to TikZ, but the boxes are reasonably easy to create. There are various ways to do them, I suggest you search this site and also take a look at the [TikZ Manual](http://ftp.fau.de/ctan/graphics/pgf/base/doc/pgfmanual.pdf).

Comment: @Alenanno But it is unlikely to be requested as homework without any kind of prior introduction, I'd hope.

Comment: @cfr Yes, you're right, if that is indeed homework, I suppose the topic must have been reached before the exercise was assigned. I was just considering the fact that while the arrows in particular are a bit tricky to position, the boxes are easier, so at least having the easy parts done would've been better, homework or not.

Comment: @Alenanno Oh, yes. I definitely agree. Then it would be reasonable to provide a little help (so long as that's OK with the instructor, of course, but that's not at all implausible).

Answer (score 2):

One way to do it (only since this is your first question):

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2pt]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[blk/.style={anchor=west,draw,minimum height=2em}, outer sep=0pt,line width=.6pt]
\draw[line width=1pt,|->] (0,0)node[left]{C}--++(1,0) coordinate(a);
\node [blk, minimum width=3em](b) at (a){4}; 
\node [blk, minimum width=2em](c) at (b.east){}; 

\node [blk, minimum width=3em, right=of c](d){6};
\node [blk, minimum width=2em](e) at (d.east){};
\draw[line width=1pt,|->] (c.center)--(d);

\node [blk, minimum width=3em, right=of e](f){};
\node [blk, minimum width=2em](g) at (f.east){Nil};  
\draw[line width=1pt,|->] (e.center)--(f);

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: How did you answer a closed question?

Comment: Frankly, I think answering this question is just plain wrong. I'm sure the instructor wants to spend time marking your solution to the homework exercise. I can't see any excuse for this. I've seen people provide a hint. But simply doing it for the student is ridiculous.

Comment: @Alenanno I'd like to know that, too.

Comment: I posted the answer a fraction of a second before the questioned was already closed!!

Comment: The question was closed 40 mins ago. You posted 11 mins ago. Would you please delete this?

Comment: There were three votes only when I posted, then it was immediately closed.

Comment: Did you start the answer before it was closed? There is a grace period where it lets you post an answer if you started it before the question was closed. And it can be very long. That would explain your answer.  cc @cfr

Comment: There is nothing wrong with answering questions

Comment: There is nothing wrong with lighting fires.

Comment: @cfr Point being? Please don't ask people to delete their answers. It's not your business. You can vote for deletion.